# How to protect data in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

Can anyone point me to example of configuration files in ElasticSearch to enable security

So far I create user with password and supperuser role

- elasticsearch-users useradd esadmin -p pswd -r superuser
- confirm that config files users and users_roles updated
- add to elasticsearch-6.6.1\config\elasticsearch.yml

```
xpack.security.enabled: true
xpack.security.authc.realms.native.type: native
xpack.security.authc.realms.native.order: 0
xpack.security.authc.realms.native.enabled: true
```

- with logstash import data from database and specify user and password in output section

```
output {
  if [type] == "products" {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        index => "products"
        user => "esadmin"
        password => "pswd"
      }
  }

}
```

And I still able to request data without authentication

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/_all/_search?q=powershot%20G"
curl --user esadmin:pswd  -X GET "localhost:9200/_all/_search?q=powershot%20G"
```

both cUrl call give me same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make sure that:

1. You are using a license that includes the xpack security features, such as the "trial" license. You can check it by running `curl -X GET "localhost:9200/_xpack/license"`
2. You have already [set the password](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/setup-passwords.html) for the `elastic` built-in user

Comment: I was wrong not believing that  even basic security not available in community edition.

Comment: Glad I helped. Does it work now? If so, please accept the answer

Comment: I've found 3rd party plugin which provide basic security. Anyway Big Thank you to you for clear things out.